# Triple boot Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot

I've already installed Windows 7 dual boot on different HDD both are Windows 7 so if I choose alongside option then Ubuntu Grub will let choose all preinstalled two OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you choose 'Install alongside...' it should keep your existing setup and use remaining space to install Ubuntu.

Bear in mind that it will attempt to shrink existing partitions if there is not enough physical space on the HD. It will also cause grub to be installed to MBR (unless you are using UEFI)

Alternatively you can also select 'Something else' and use the partition editor to designate partitions and allocate space manually.